# How to use Promise.all using Axios Async Await

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, nuxt.js

I have this Axios Async Await code in Nuxt.js, I am not sure on how and where to put the `Promise.all` here. I am trying to promise the `getThemes()` and `getData()`. Could somebody help me with the `Promise.all` code?

And do I have to put the `Promise.all` in the `mounted()`?

```
mounted() {
    this.getData(this.$route.params.id);
    this.getThemes();
  },

  methods: {
    async getThemes() {
      this.loading = true;
      await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-themes`, {}).then((response) => {
        this.theme = response.data.data;
        this.selected = this.theme.filter(t => this.themeId === t.id)[0].id;
        this.loading = false;
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.errormsg = error.response.data.message;
      });
    },

    async getData(id) {
      this.loading = true;
      await axios
        .get(`${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-templates/${id}`)
        .then(({
          data
        }) => {
          this.templateName = data.data.name;
          this.templateCode = data.data.content;
          this.themeId = data.data.theme_id;
          this.loading = false;
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.errormsg = error.response.data.message;
        });
    },

    async patchData(id) {
      await axios.put(`${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-templates/${this.$route.params.id}`, {
        name: this.templateName,
        content: this.templateCode,
        theme_id: this.selected
      }).then((response) => {
        this.results = response.data;
        this.loading = false;
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.errormsg = error.response.data.message;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you are asking more than one thing here, my answer solves what you are actually asking, but maybe you should avoid setting `this` on `getThemes()` and `getData()`, instead, just use the return value of your promises inside `mounted()`. Also, you are using `await` poorly, you shouldn't be using `then` nor `catch`but a `try catch` block.

Comment: Another problem in your code is that if both `getThemes()' and `getData()` fail, one of them will replace the `errormsg` from the other. You can catch both errors and concatenate them once you use `Promise.all`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, so do you think I should replace all of the methods? I'm pretty new at this Asnyc Await thing and the code above isn't mine, it was made by my co-worker and I have to fix his code.

Comment: You can start playing with my code and its mocked async requests, as you can see, there is no `then`. In order to catch errors, you should implement one or more `try catch' blocks.

Comment: You can also replace `getPromise()` with your axios calls: `getPromise(1)` would become `axios.get(\`${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-themes\`, {})`.

Comment: You can do `Promise.all([this.getThemes(), this.getData(this.$route.params.id)])`, but what do you then want to do with that promise in `mounted`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> A  [Promise](http://hthttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promisetp://) which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.

Reference - [Async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

So you can do it as follows

```
{
  mounted() {
    this.loading = true;
    Promise.all([this.getThemes(), this.getData(this.$route.params.id)])
      .then(values => {
        //first return value
        this.theme = values[0];
        this.selected = this.theme.filter(t => this.themeId === t.id)[0].id;
        //second return value
        this.templateName = values[1].name;
        this.templateCode = values[1].content;
        this.themeId = values[1].theme_id;

        this.loading = false;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.errormsg = error.response.data.message;
        this.loading = false;
      });
  },
  methods: {
    async getThemes() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-themes`,
        {}
      );
      return response.data.data;
    },
    async getData(id) {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-templates/${id}`
      );

      return response.data.data;
    }
  }
};
```

Then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) passing the two async functions in an array as an argument.

Comment: you can put `this.loading = false` in a `then(...)` after `catch(...)` which works similar to `always(...)` in jQuery:

`.then( values => { ...}).catch( error => {...}).then( () => { this.loading = false; });`

Answer (score 3):

```
here example how to wait axios all fetch
let url1="https://stackoverflow.com";
let url2="https://stackoverflow.com/questions";
let request1=axios.get(url1);
let request2=axios.get(url2);
let [answer1,answer2]=await axios.all([request1,request2]);
console.log(answer1.data);
console.log(answer2.data);
```

Comment: I want to just comment here for anyone looking for the answer, that *this* should really be the accepted answer. Axios has this stuff built in. Unfortunately, the accepted answer reinvents the wheel and results in bad coding practices and bloat.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to wait for both `getThemes` and `getData` to be finished:

```
   mounted() {
     this.loadData();
   },
   methods: {
     async loadData() {
       this.loading = true
       try {
         await Promise.all([this.getThemes(), this.getData(this.$route.params.id)])
       } catch (error) {
         this.errormsg = error.message;
       } finally {
         this.loading = false
       }
     }
    getThemes() {
       return axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-themes`, {
       }).then((response) => {
         this.theme = response.data.data;
         this.selected = this.theme.filter(t => this.themeId === t.id)[0].id;
       })
     },

    getData(id) {
       return axios
         .get(`${process.env.API_URL}/v1/communication/email-templates/${id}`)
         .then(({ data }) => {
           this.templateName = data.data.name;
           this.templateCode = data.data.content;
           this.themeId = data.data.theme_id;
         })
    },
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying and it seems that is the way to do it, but I have another problem now, there is a console error stating "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at _id.vue?e97a:100" The error was in "this.errormsg = error.response.data.message;" inside the async loadData(). Could you help me a bit more?

Comment: I tried the code and sometimes it works but sometimes it shows the error, just like my previous code.